# Why does binding image path to Image.Source does not work this way

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, binding, properties

I have an image path declared as following:

```
public static string _edit_vector32 = "pack://application:,,,/Resources/Images/Icons/32/edit-vector2-32.png";
```

I try to add a simple property that returns an ImageSource to my ViewModel as following:

```
public ImageSource ClockImage
{
    get
    { 
        return new BitmapImage(new Uri(RuntimeSettings._clock24)) as ImageSource;
    }
 }
```

Then bind in XAML:

```
 <Image Source="{Binding ClockImage}"/>
```

Why does this not work, while:

```
 <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/Images/Icons/32/edit-vector2-32.png"/>
```

Works as expected?

Comment: The first case should work too, are you sure you are binding to the correct property? Maybe the datacontext is different because of the binding of an enclosing element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/Images/Icons/32/edit-vector2-32.png"/>
```

This works because `ImageSource` has a value converter (`ImageSourceConverter`) attached to it, which automatically converts strings to image sources.

The first case should work too (and does in my test project).